# JS: How to make multiline strings appear on one line?

Tags: javascript, string, conditional-rendering, multilinestring

I have a string in my JS code that I want to include three parts, each rendered conditionally.

```
let a = `
    ${condition1 ? <text1> : ""}
    ${condition2 ? <text2> : ""}
    ${condition3 ? <text3> : ""}
`
```

I want `a` to be all on one line, but this renders on multiple lines. The reason I wrote the code on multiple lines is for ease of reading.

Is there a way to write the code on multiple lines but have the string render on one?

Comment: Remove the line breaks or don't use template string literals.

Comment: @ThomasSablik If I don't use template string literals, is there a way to do the conditional rendering that I'm doing?

Comment: `let a  = (condition1 ? <text1> : "") + (condition2 ? <text2> : "") + (condition3 ? <text3> : "")`

Comment: @ThomasSablik Note that I wanted to write the code on separate lines for ease of reading. condition1 condition2 etc are pretty long.

Comment: Unless you're rendering the string in a `<pre>` block, the line breaks should turn into spaces when rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid template string literals

```
let a  = (condition1 ? <text1> : "")
       + (condition2 ? <text2> : "")
       + (condition3 ? <text3> : "");
```

Example:

```js
let a  = (true ? "text1" : "")
       + (false ? "text2" : "")
       + (true ? "text3" : "");
    
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add backslashes (`\`) after each line.

```js
const condition1 = true, 
      condition2 = true, 
      condition3 = true;

let a = `\
${condition1 ? 'text1' : ""} \
${condition2 ? 'text2' : ""} \
${condition3 ? 'text3' : ""}
`;

console.log(a)
```

Hint: Ensure that you remove spaces.